# How to find process with specific windows registry path in C#

Tags: c#

I want to write code that get string (Windows registry path) and give a process or programs that use this path, how can I implement this scenario?

```
var registryKey=RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

var subKeys = registryKey.OpenSubKey(@"HARDWARE\ACPI\DSDT\ALASKA\A_M_I\00000031");
var subKeysValues = subKeys.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to get values of my specific registry path, but it doesn't give process or program that is using this path

Comment: Please post some code from which you are starting to implement your project

Comment: I edited my post and post my codes

Comment: Do you want the program that created the key? or an event whenever a program reads/writes to a key? Or some historical log of all the programs that have ever accessed the key?

Comment: I want a program or programs reads/writes to a key

Comment: I do not think there is any easy way to do that in c#. There are registry events to monitor *changes*, but they do not give the process id of writer. So you might need to do some low level OS hooks or kernel driver, not something c# is at all suitable for.

Comment: You can use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor registry accesses.